# Finder - disable appending of " (1)" when saving same file name, ie no versioning desired, overwrite original as default

Tags: finder, filesystem

Firstly, I searched this fervently trying terms such as:

1. "finder disable file save versioning"
2. "disable finders file save adding (1)"
3. "finder save overwrite by default"
4. "finder overwrite save file"...

Problem: When saving a file to my desktop (anywhere), for example a file named "abc.123", if a file with this exact name already exists, Finder's save dialog with automatically append a space followed by a (1) forcing me to place my cursor in the new file name dialog and erase this portion it added to the file name. Having to process many files in repetition make this an unpleasant experience. My intention is to always overwrite the version I am saving over.

The file it suggests is "abc (1).123", I would like to disable this from happening.

The experience I desire is when saving "abc.123" over an existing "abc.123" is the file save dialog respects the original file name and does not molest it any further without my consent.  Is this possible?

Comment: Applications usually overwrite by default. From where do you trigger saving the file?

Comment: Apparently this was an issue 3 years ago w/ Linux too, being a web developer having to save files from browsers where this occurs ie optimizing/cropping images, this is a frequent impedance to my work flow - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192520/disable-auto-number-duplicate-file-names-upon-save-dialog

Comment: @nohillside typically web browser, many diff types, as for web development testing

Comment: So maybe this is an app feature request, more so of applications such as Chrome or FireFox instead of Apple/Mac community? I was thinking this was a Finder feature but maybe I am incorrect, does anyone know this answer?

Comment: This is usually an application convention.  Can you give an example of where this is happening?  Also, the term “versioning” refers to backup/recovery; as changes are saved, the file *versioned* within Time Machine so you can go back to a particular version of the file.

Comment: Also, when you copy/move files from one folder to another and a file with the same name exists, you’ll normally get a dialog asking you to “Overwrite, Keep Both, or Cancel”.

Comment: Saving pages from Safari just overwrites. Downloads may not, though, and I didn't check other browsers.

Comment: Seems to be an experienced no matter the OS or all OS's follow this same assumption that when saving an exact file, the dialog is forced to append a version as a big brother protection method of sorts, here's a windows user requesting the same - https://superuser.com/questions/1565526/how-to-remove-the-1-suffix-from-the-name-suggestion-in-windows-10-save-downl

Comment: I would not want this only in Chrome, I would prefer the choice of enabling or disabling this. With unix at the core, I had hoped there was a clever override discovered.

Comment: Give this command a shot:  `defaults delete -g ApplePersistence -bool false` Keep in mind, this only affects Apps like Preview, TextEdit, and maybe even Safari.  I doubt it will work in Chome/Firefox/Edge, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Allan I'll give this a shot. I think I'll replace -g with -app 'Finder' on a clone drive before attempting the global method. I'll report back if it's the answer.

Comment: I totally botched it.  It’s supposed to be `defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool false`. To remove that setting, use `delete`.

Comment: @Allan tyvm, this is the answer, however I modified -g to -app safari to first test in safari, went to tinypng service, uploaded file and opened the save file dialog to find it did not change the file name and when I clicked save it prompted the existing file overwrite protection notice of which is simply a click to override.

Comment: I’ll write up an answer combing my two comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the auto-rename setting for files when they are saved, issue the command

```
defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool false
```

This will turn off the appending of “(1…n)” on files to prevent overwriting.  You can do this on a per app basisis by specifying the application:

```
defaults write -a “Preview” ApplePresistence -bool false
```

It’s important to note that this is an application convention, no so much a Finder one.  So, it will work for Apple apps like TextEdit, Preview, Safari, etc.  Chrome and Firefox will have their own settings.

To remove the setting, use the `delete` command

```
defaults delete -g ApplePresistence
```